# How to delete Calendar items where the end date occurs before the start date?

Tags: sync, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2013, under Sync Issues > Local Failure, I have some Calendar items that will not delete. The error message says "The end date you entered occurs before the start date."

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fix the calendar entries to have a proper end date (one that's AFTER the start date), and then delete them?

Comment: I am unable to open the Calendar item as it gives a similar error. I was able to delete the entries in Local Failures by using MFCMAPI.

Answer (score 2):

- Download [MFCMAPI](http://web.archive.org/web/20141201174219/http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/).
- Navigate to QuickStart > Open Folder
- Select Local Failure folder
- Select the offending item and press Delete

You can choose to move it to Delete Items, but you may need to select Hard Delete (unrecoverable) if you have issues moving it to the Deleted Items or emptying the trash after it is in Delete Items.

[image]

Thanks to [Diane Poremsky from Slipstick](http://web.archive.org/web/20141201174235/http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/unable-to-dismiss-or-delete-an-outlook-calendar/f1e3d297-24ca-4721-8788-1f11e811cc21) for the solution.